# Query property vs Xamarin Essentials preferences

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is it wise or am I doing the right way to use preferences over query property on passing objects from one form to another? Or should i only use it for some instances like login access boolean ? Im just curious because I've been using preferences over query property this whole time and I dont know if im doing it right, Thanks.

Comment: since you haven't provide any code or specific samples it's impossible to comment on what you're doing.  But generally speaking, Preferences is not intended for passing parameters when navigating between pages.

Comment: Preferences are intended for information that should persist long term. For example, still be there after an app restart. Not intended for passing data around.

Comment: If you create the page programmatically, you can simply set a public property. `var page = new MyPage();` `page.MyProperty = ..`.